# Svg height inside button is different from text

Tags: css

How to fix it?

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hypatia-fotls?file=/src/App.tsx).

[image]

```
html {
  font-size: 18px; //user-defined
}

.s1 {
  height: 1rem;
}

.b1 {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

---

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const MenuSvg = () => {
  return (
    <svg
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      strokeWidth="2"
      stroke="black"
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeLinejoin="round"
      className="s1"
    >
      <line x1="3" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line>
      <line x1="3" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line>
      <line x1="3" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="b1">Hello</button>
      <button className="b1">
        <MenuSvg />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: display:block to svg + vertical-align:top to button

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://i.imgur.com/ktNtUsu.png

Comment: `font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1rem;` to first button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `display:block` to SVG to remove the space below it and use `line-height` to define the height of the first button. Note that button element have default font-size applied by the browser so you may need to override it:

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.s1 {
  height: 1rem;
  display:block;
}

.b1 {
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size:1rem;
  vertical-align:top; /* to fix the alignment */
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div><button class="b1">Hello</button><button class="b1"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="s1"><line x1="3" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line><line x1="3" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line><line x1="3" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line></svg></button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @oldboy myabe there is something wrong with your code (PS: if you want to message me better use this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign  instead of comments to not confuse other users)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because they are naturally two different heights. The div containing `Hello` is the height of `Hello` plus padding. In the div containing the lines, the lines are a total height of `1rem` plus padding.

If you want these divs to be the same height, you may want to add an explicit height to both divs - this will ensure they are the same height.

In your Sandbox, if you remove the `b1` class from your code, you will be able to see that `Hello` and the lines are naturally two different heights.

[image]